# Visual studio - select word with hyphen

Tags: visual-studio, ide

When you ctrl+click or double click a word in the Visual Studio text editor, it stops the selection at a hyphen. So, for example, you cannot select a full GUID with ctrl+click. Is there a way to remove the hyphen as a word separator?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an extension that solves this issue for visual studio. ["Select Hyphenated"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thirdwaffle.SelectHyphenated) @ marketplace.visualstudio.com

There is also a setting in vscode:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

By removing the hyphen, double clicking selects whole hyphenated words.
I also removed the period and hash for selecting css classes and ids.

Comment: Thank you, that works (the extension). Oddly it only works when you double click, not when you ctrl+click. I am in more of a habbit of ctrl+click as 95% of the time I am about to copy/cut it, so having the ctrl key pressed helps!